unknown error 0x80080005 trying to read xlsm file in tcl
I am reading xlsm files in tcl and the code is working.  But every once in a while it throws an error.  error: 0x80080005 while executing tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application.  The code runs but will thro the error once in while.  Is there a way to disconnect the excelApp object or destroy it?  The code runs in a loop so the proc is getting called multiple times.
proc readSpreadSheet{fileToRead} {

set excelApp [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
set workbooks [$excelApp Workbooks]
set workbook [$workbooks Open $fileToRead]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
set cells [$worksheet Cells]
# Reading data to list 
......

$excelApp Quit
delete $excelApp
set excelApp {}
return [list $columns $rows]
}

